# wp_redirect() function is not working in WP admin

Tags: php, redirect, plugins, wordpress

I will try following code for redirect in wordpress admin.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
wp_redirect('admin.php?page=job-creation');
}
```

i also try `wp_redirect('admin.php?page=job-creation');` instead of

```
wp_safe_redirect('admin.php?page=job-creation');
```

and

```
header('location: admin.php?page=job-creation');
```

All codes are working fine in localhost. but it does not working in online(www.example.com).

Help me anyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is for your web server configuration, you can't use header function every where in code.
Instead of using header, use this :

```
print('<script>window.location.href="admin.php?page=job-creation"</script>');
```

This is a simple javascript code for redirect to another page.

**UPDATE**

For more information about using `header` visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in that plugin which must b activate.

```
function callback($buffer) {
    // modify buffer here, and then return the updated code
    return $buffer;
}

function buffer_start() {
    ob_start("callback");
}

function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}

add_action('init', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

Comment: I already got the solution. then why you are putting answer after long days here. :)

Comment: @BoopathiRajan The more answers could be better or helpful to someone else in some other way... I hope this solves your query...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should always `exit` after you using [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect).

Secondly, you should specify an absolute URI. Use [`admin_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) for that.

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
  wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=job-creation' ) );
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ob_start()` function before redirecting if url is correct.